# Prove $3^n$ divides any number formed from $3^n$ identical digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know this is a repost of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349952/showing-that-a-3n-digit-number-whose-digits-are-all-equal-is-divisible-by-3), however I had some trouble understanding the answers as I am new to number theory. I asked my doubt in a comment but got no reply.

One of the answers says:

> A number whose digits are all equal and of length $3^n$ is thus of the
>   form $c = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{3^n-1} a \cdot 10^i = a \dfrac{10^{3^n}-1}{10-1}$ by the geometric series.
>
> Since we have to account for the possibility that $a = 1$ we need to
>   show that $3^n \mid \dfrac{10^{3^n}-1}9$, i.e. $3^{n+2} \mid 10^{3^n}-1$.
>
> This we can do by induction: Base case is trivial, suppose $3^{n+2}\mid 10^{3^n}-1$.
>
> Then we have $10^{3^n} \equiv 1 \pmod {3^{n+2}}$, and so: $10^{3^n}\equiv 1 + k 3^{n+2} \pmod {3^{n+3}}$. Now compute $10^{3^{n+1}} = \left(10^{3^n}\right)^3$ modulo $3^{n+3}$.

I can't understand how can we write $10^{3^n} \equiv 1 \pmod {3^{n+2}}$ as $10^{3^n} \equiv 1 + k 3^{n+2} \pmod {3^{n+3}}$. And how to proceed further to prove $10^{3^{n+1}} \equiv 1$ (mod $3^{n+3})$. I figured we could cube both sides of $10^{3^n} \equiv 1 + k 3^{n+2} \pmod {3^{n+3}}$, however it leads to a lot of extra terms on right hand side of the equation.

Comment: By definition of $\pmod{3^{n+2}}$, we have $3^{n+2}$ divides $10^{3^n}-1$ . So $10^{3^n}-1= k 3^{n+2}$ for some integer $k$. This is then certainly true $\pmod {3^{n+3}}$ as well. As for all those extra terms, they should all be $0 \pmod {3^{n+3}}$ so they disappear.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you. This is exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\frac{10^{3^{n+1}}-1}9=\frac{a^3-1}9=\frac{10^{3^n}-1}9(a^2+a+1)$$
where $a=10^{3^n}$. The induction step boils down to confirming that
$3$ divides $a^2+a+1$. If we could prove that $a\equiv1\pmod 3$ we could
confirm that.

Comment: I can't understand how can we write $10^{3^n} \equiv 1 \pmod {3^{n+2}}$ as $10^{3^n} \equiv 1 + k 3^{n+2} \pmod {3^{n+3}}$? Can you help me with this?

Comment: @shiva: By definition of $\pmod{3^{n+2}}$, we have $3^{n+2}$ divides $10^{3^n}-1$ . So $10^{3^n}-1= k 3^{n+2}$ for some integer $k$. This is then certainly true $\pmod {3^{n+3}}$ as well.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Oh, so does this mean we could replace $\pmod {3^{n+3}}$ with anything, right?

Comment: @shiva Yes it does, though we need $3^{n+3}$ here for the rest of the proof.